# "Signal 11: Segmentation fault" error after switching PostgreSQL Alpine image to Debian with upgrade from 12.3 to 12.6

Tags: postgresql, docker, raspberry-pi, arm, alpine-linux

I have a PostgreSQL database for some sensoric data on my Raspberry Pi. It runs on the `postgres:12-alpine` tag without automatic updates yet. Before the update, I got the following version string:

```
('PostgreSQL 12.3 on arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 32-bit',)
```

After I noticed that it was a bit out of date, I pulled the latest image with the following version string:

```
('PostgreSQL 12.6 on arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 32-bit',)
```

This worked, but I noticed that new inserted sensor data got a timestamp from 2038 when using `NOW()`. It seems complicated to solve with Alpine, maybe also an Alpine issue. I already had trouble with issues created by their musl usage. Since the normal image is not too much larger (109MB vs 62MB), I switched to the regular `postgres:12` image.

Since the container was started with the normal Debian image, the startup failed:

```
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:05.213 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 on arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 32-bit
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:05.214 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:05.214 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:05.226 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:11.083 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 20) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:11.084 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:00:14.480 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
pms_postgres_1 exited with code 1
```

Same issue with the Debian image:

```
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:19.733 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 32-bit
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:19.738 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:19.738 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:19.752 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:28.520 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 27) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:28.520 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
postgres_1  | 2021-03-31 17:11:35.024 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
pms_postgres_1 exited with code 1
```

It's also not working with the latest 12.6 release. I'm assuming that the problem was, I switched from Alpine to Debian AND also updated the PostgreSQL version with the pull. So PSQL 12.3 on Alpine was upgraded to PSQL 12.6 on Debian.

Why does this *Segmentation fault* error occur and how can I fix it?

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.4'
volumes:
  #postgres-data_new:
  postgres-data:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.6
    #image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    #image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./create-tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-tables.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xx
      POSTGRES_DB: xxx
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

`create-tables.sql` just creates a very basic measure data table:

```
create table if not exists sensors(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    soilMoisture NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    temp NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    dateTime timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I'm doubtful this would have caused the sigsegv, but when doing a similar thing I noticed the user id of the postgres user in the alpine image was different from that in the debian-based image, and the file ownership was wrong after the upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem is an outdated libseccomp  version on the host: libseccomp 2.4.2 or newer and Docker to 19.03.9 or newer are required. But my RPI has just 2.3.3 from the repos:

```
# dpkg -l | grep libseccomp
ii  libseccomp2:armhf                   2.3.3-4                             armhf        high level interface to Linux seccomp filter
```

There are two ways to fix this, **but only for new containers** with fresh volumes. I still couldn't get my existing database from the volume working with that.

### #1 Install a newer version manually and bypass the package manager

At least until the repos got updated. I guess this will happen after some time, then we can use the version provided by Raspbians repos again.

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
```

### #2 Disable it in `docker-compose.yml` as workaround

```
security_opt:
  - seccomp:unconfined
```

But this will [*reduce the security of the host against malicious code in the container*](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.13.0#time64_requirements), so updating the library seems to be a more secure solution.